# STE as Data Contract?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

Is there any way to share self tracking entities with client tier(from server tier which is WCF) like Data Contract.
I mean, do not include any assembly with STE to client, just get them from server e.g.

If "DAL" is the service reference, I want some like:

```
DAL.SomeEntity = new DAL.SomeEntity();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self tracking entities must be shared with client in form of code or assembly. That is the main requirement to use them because they are not just a contract they also contain logic responsible for change tracking and this logic cannot be shared with the client in any other form.

Comment: Thanks! So i need to use DTO or POCO.

Comment: If you use DTO or POCO why did you use STEs? Their purpose is to only for scenarios where they are transferred to client.

Comment: The purpose of STEs was get lover DataBase load. As I understad while we calling e.g. context.DeleteObject(someobj) it`s executing only DELETE query, finding id object by key. In case of POCO i need to select proper object from context, and then delete it, so it`s two querys SELECT & DELETE.